# How to make proper use of 'h' & 'w' with 'xstack' filter, specifically how to avoid clipping and borders?

Tags: ffmpeg

I was trying to create a video that combined 10 other videos in a grid of 2x5. When I run the commands below, I end up with the first column's videos being cropped on the left hand side, and there is a large green gap between each video. All the videos are the same resolution.

Included here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaySN.jpg

ffmpeg -i "movie1" -i "movie2" -i "movie3" -i "movie4" -i "movie5" -i "movie6" -i "movie7" -i "movie8" -i "movie9" -i "movie10" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v][4:v][5:v][6:v][7:v][8:v][9:v]xstack=inputs=10:layout=0_0|0_w0|0_w0+w1|0_w0+w1+w2|0_w0+w1+w2+w3|h0_0|h0_w0|h0_w0+w1|h0_w0+w1+w2|h0_w0+w1+w2+w3[v]" -map "[v]" output

Answer (score 0):

Since all videos have the same resolution, use

`ffmpeg -i "movie1" -i "movie2" -i "movie3" -i "movie4" -i "movie5" -i "movie6" -i "movie7" -i "movie8" -i "movie9" -i "movie10" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v][4:v][5:v][6:v][7:v][8:v][9:v]xstack=inputs=10:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0|0_2*h0|w0_2*h0|0_3*h0|w0_3*h0|0_4*h0|w0_4*h0[v]" -map "[v]" output`